# A modulus inequality involving a minimum

Tags: analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis

When studying Fourier analysis, I have come across inequalities of the form
$$
|\hat{K}_j(\xi)|\leq \min (|2^j\xi|^{-a},|2^j\xi|)
$$ 
where we have the dilation operator $K_j(x)=2^{-jn}K(2^{-j}x),~j\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $K\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (ie, $K$ is an integrable function over $\mathbb{R}^n$) has compact support. Also, 
$$
|I(t)|\leq \min (1,|t|^{-1})
$$
where $I(t)$ is the integral
$$
I(t)=\int^2_1 e^{-2\pi irt}\frac{dr}{r}.
$$
Is there a name for this type of inequality? Is there a more general form of this inequality? How do we go about proving this statement?

Please accept my apologies in advance if this is an easy UG inequality that I should know.

Thanks in advance for your help and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no special name for these inequalities. Let's prove the last one. On the one hand
$$
|I(t)|\le\int_1^2\frac{dr}r=\log2<1.
$$
On the other, integration by parts gives
$$
I(t)=\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i\,t}\Bigl(-\frac{e^{-2\pi irt}}{r}\,\Bigr|_1^2-\int^2_1 e^{-2\pi irt}\,\frac{dr}{r^2}\Bigr)
$$
and
$$
|I(t)|\le\frac{1}{|t|}.
$$